# get col and row with NA values

Tags: r

Suppose I have a `matrix` like this:

```
d <- matrix(1,5,10)
d[c(3,4),6] <- NA
d
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1   NA    1    1    1     1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1   NA    1    1    1     1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

How do I get the location of the entries that are `NA`?

`which(is.na(d))` gives me

```
[1] 28 29
```

but I want to know the `col` and `row`, in this case I want to get something like:

```
[1] [3,6]
[2] [4,6]
```

Is that possible?

Comment: `which(is.na(d), arr.ind = TRUE)`